# calling a C++ function from C# and sending data back to the C#

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, asynchronous

I have a C# application that calls functions in a DLL written in C++. The calls work fine and the code is executed using this method in the C#:

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll")]
public static extern void Function();

static void Main()
{
    Function();
}
```

Now this works, I need the executing C++ code to send back the text to the C# where it can be displayed in a panel.

The text is "stage one..." executes code...then "stage two" etc, showing the processes running. Just basic stuff. I'm not sure how to approach this as I'm not a C++ guy. My main skills are .NET.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using callbacks in C++ and sign them in C#

C++ part

```
typedef void (CALLBACK *pfNotifyMessage)(LPTSTR);

extern "C" AFX_API_EXPORT void SetNotifyMessage(pfNotifyMessageType pfNotify);
extern "C" AFX_API_EXPORT void Function();
```

In C++ Function call make call of pfNotifyMessage

C# part

```
public delegate void NotifyMessage(string message);

[DllImport("myDLL.dll")]
public static extern void SetNotifyMessage(NotifyMessage notify);

[DllImport("myDLL.dll")]
public static extern void Function();
```

in С# assign delegate with function

Comment: hi the C++ code causes a number of errors when adding to the code

Comment: its just a header for c++ lib , you need to implement callback

Comment: You may see this article to get basic info of writing callbacks http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/10/11/simple-callback-function/

Comment: is "EXTERN_C AFX_API_EXPORT" valid c++ code? I only ask this as if I put this in google a load of rubbish comes through.

Comment: this code does not work. i have added it to my C++ and have a number of errors:syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';' 
 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
'pfNotifyMessageType' : undeclared identifier 
 syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'pfNotify' 
 'SetNotifyMessage' : illegal use of type 'void' 
syntax error : ')' 
 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: pfNotifyMessageType is not registred type. its a pointer to function. You need to implement that part on your own. http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9902/Using_callbacks_in_DLLs.htm see this article how to write callbacks and use them in dll. Hope it helps